# How do I bind following object with following model?

Tags: html, angularjs, select

This is my object

`$scope.status = [{
            "code": "CNA",
            "name": "Consignee Not Available"
        }, {
            "code": "TBD",
            "name": "To Be Delivered"
        }, {
            "code": "CRA",
            "name": "Consignee Refused To Accept"
        }, {
            "code": "D",
            "name": "Delivered"
        } ]`

my HTML is as follows

`<select ng-options="status.name for status in status" ng-model="awb.delivery_fail_reason">
<option value="">Please Select Status</option>
</select>`

so what I want is

1. when user selects the status `To be Delivered`
   my  model variable 
   `awb.delivery_fail_reason` should be set to `TBD`
2. when model `awb.delivery_fail_reason` is `TBD` it should automatically set select to `To Be Delivered`
   Is this possible ?

Comment: try `status.code as status.name for status in status`

Comment: I never knew we can do this type of stuff.
Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, I have moved it to the answer section for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
status.code as status.name for status in status
```

Answer (score 0):

make changes in html as below

```
  <select ng-model="awb.delivery_fail_reason">
              <option value="">Please Select Status</option> 
              <option ng-repeat="s in status" value="{{s.code}}">{{s.name}}</option>

              </select>
```

try fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1489/

Comment: Word of caution !! Never ever use ng-repeat with option.
There is already ng-options which will allow you to repeat over objects.